# Xively PUT request error HTTP 411, Content-Length Required?

Tags: json, http, arduino, xively

So I've got an arduino uno with a CC3000 shield attached and I want to push data to my Xively account:
https://xively.com/develop/yS4XfViIIEEkB94MJ4zs
However I get this error when I connect:

```
Connected!
Request DHCP
api.xively.com -> 64.94.18.120
Data Lengthz

PUT /v2/feeds/97346308.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.xively.com
X-ApiKey:mykey
Content-Length: z
Connection: close


{"version":"1.0.0","datastreams" : [ {"id" : "Longitude","current_value" : ""},{"id" : "Latitude","current_value" : ""}]}
Connected to Xively server.
--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Date: Fri, 08 Aug 2014 13:19:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 181
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>411 Length Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>411 Length Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that error 411 is a call for content length but I've alread declared this in my header and I still get this error. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Length` value must be a sequence of digits. What you sent is a letter, so the server complained that it didn't get your header in the correct format.

Instead of:

```
Content-Length: z
```

Use:

```
Content-Length: 0
```

If you are actually including data in the body of your request, the length should be the number of octets in the encoded body.